# Can a Perl script set the address in the browser?

Tags: .htaccess, cgi-bin

I would love it if my Perl script can change the address in the browser.  Not to try and hide things, or be funny.  But for cleanliness sake.

**www.example.com/billing**

looks much better than:

**www.example.com/cgi-bin/billing.pl?userid=0000&inv=1234**

I realize browsers probably have high security measures to prevent phishers from being more tricky, but what gives me some hope that this is possible is that I placed the following line in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

and if I go to www.example.com/nonexistent the browser will go back to the main page, but the address bar still has the nonexistent address.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this consists of two parts: certainly you can change the URL shown in the browser by sending a redirection header from your script, but that will only change the URL _after_ the request has been sent and responded to. What you are actually looking for is "rewriting", that has nothing to do with your script but is a feature of the http server relaying the incoming request to your script. Here you can define other URLs to react on the way you want. But for the example you give you will have to point out a way how to know the user and invoice ID, rewriting cannot make those up...

Comment: @arkascha What I meant was keeping it clean. The URL is after someone fills out example/form … would just prefer they land on the right page with a cleaner URL.  Does that make sense?   And is it possible?

Comment: That is something different than what you asked in the question. For that you do not need rewriting, but you should simply make a HTTP POST request instead of a HTTP GET request which makes more sense anyway from a semantic point of view, when you are talking about a form submission which was never mentioned before.

Comment: @arkascha Not really. I was giving an example to your first comment.  That’s not my situation.  You commented on a very specific issue. I’m just trying to find out if I can change/clean up what’s in the address bar. That’s all. If it’s not possible or is possible.

Comment: I think I answered to that in my first comment.

Comment: @arkascha So I need to search about "rewriting URLS?

Comment: As already written: there are two ways to interpret what you ask, whether the URL should be clean _before_ the request and you are looking for a way to internally rewrite the requests (how do you know request details like user and invoice id then?) or you process the incoming request and _then_ redirect the browser to a "clean URL" by means of a simply http header you sent out from your script. It depends on what it is you want which has not yet become clear from your statements. You will find tutorials and answers for both.

Comment: My goal was just to have receiving Perl script change the address to make it look cleaner.  From what I’m interpreting from the comments I need to do that with my script redirecting

Comment: OK, that is the second option I mentioned. So your script processes the incoming request and then sends out an http header to the requesting client in the response. That redirection header makes the client request the URL it got redirected to, so the response should not contain any payload, only maybe a success message, since the client will not render whatever response you send back because of the redirection. So read about how to send a "Location:" http header by means of perl.